# Questions about coordinate ring of a closed subvariety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to prove the following statement:

> If $L$ is a closed subvariety of $M$, then there is a surjection from $\mathbb{C}[M]$ to $\mathbb{C}[L]$?

I think that maybe this follows from definitions. But I don't know how to prove it rigorously. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mind putting your definition of a variety?

Comment: Probably you mean *affine varieties*, and then it would be better to say so.

Comment: The proof is also going to depend very much on how you defined $\mathbb C[X]$ for a (presumably) affine $X$.  The definition I'm used to makes this essentially trivial, so I suspect it's not the definition you're using.

Comment: Also on how you define "closed subvariety."